# Eval emacs init.el from CLI

Tags: emacs

I want to eval my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file periodically from CLI (cron) since it generates other files that I use in my projects according to some extra data.

Something like "emacs -q -eval-file ~/.emacs.d/init.el", or something like this.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has an `--eval` option that you can use, details are [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments). But if you do this a lot, you may not want to start the entire emacs all the time. Instead, you can run the emacs-server and then simply use the much more light-weight `emacsclient`; see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html#Invoking-emacsclient).